# DB2 ODBC converting NULL floats and ints to ~0

Tags: sql, db2, odbc

Querying DB2 from python using ODBC, I am seeing `NULL` values converted to 0 (on Linux, seemingly corrupt but close to 0 on Mac M1 -- even more worryingly).

This is using the db2 docker image started like this:

```
docker run -itd --name db2 --privileged=true -p 50000:50000 -e LICENSE=accept -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=xxxxx -e DBNAME=testdb -v <db storage dir>:/database ibmcom/db2
```

Code as follows recreates the issue:

```py
import pyodbc

cs = "Driver={ODBC Driver v11.5.7 for DB2};Database=xxxxx;Hostname=xxxx;Port=50000;Protocol=TCPIP;Uid=xxxx;Pwd=xxxx;"
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cs)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
crsr.execute("SELECT CAST(NULL AS INT), CAST(NULL AS REAL) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1");
print(crsr.messages)
print(crsr.fetchall())
```

Outputs:

```
❯ python float-test.py
[]
[(2, 4.2439915814e-314)]
```

Is it expected that I can't retrieve NULL values as plain data types?  It seems to be allowed in PostgreSQL.  I know I can cast around this but would rather not, obviously.

**Extra Info**

It does seem that the ODBC driver version 11.5.7 from Fix Central suffers this issue whilst the 11.5.6 version from https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli does not.

Comment: I assume you mean `cast(NULL as REAL)` instead of `cast(Nan as Real)`. If I use native ibm_db interface then  I get None, None  for the result. If I use the dbi interface instead, then  I also get None,None.  But using pyodbc, I get your symptom. Is there some problem with pyodbc?

Comment: Sorry, yip -- adjusted the question.  Interesting; pyodbc doesn't seem problematic for postgres though, so I had assumed it was more a db2 thing.  Maybe it's around the interface between those 2 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, it appears pyodbc is impacted and both plain ibm_db and DBI are not impacted (both return None, None). So at least there is a workaround.

The reason for the behaviour deifference is that pyodbc is using `SQLGetData()` while the other two use the `SQLBindCol()` methods of extracting the result set data.

IBM's clidriver on Linux x64, `SQLGetData()` sets the `(SQLLEN *)` StrLen_Or_IndPtr parameter to `SQL_NULL_DATA` when the value of the column in result-set is NULL. But the problem is that IBMs clidrver sets StrLen_or_IndPtr to SQL_NULL_DATA (as int, 4 bytes), when pyodbc code expects it to SQL_NULL_DATA (as SQLLEN, 8bytes on Linux x64) as `SQLLEN` is the documented datatype for the StrLen_or_IndPtr argument.

Therefore the comparison in pyodbc getdata.cpp `GetDataDouble()` :

```
if ( cbFetched == SQL_NULL_DATA )
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
```

will be false, causing the code to return an unitialised variable instead of Py_None.

I do not know if the maintainers of pyodbc run their tests against a Db2-LUW product, but it looks like other parts of the code could suffer the same problem and other issues may lurk. Consider asking on github what is the support policy for Db2-LUW in pyodbc.

If you have a support contract, IBM should also be asked to comment on their reason for not respecting the datatype of StrLen_Or_IndPtr when writing SQL_NULL_DATA to this parameter on Linux x64.

Comment: Thanks for going into so much detail -- very much appreciated.